# How do I search though related tables in access and have the results displayed in a list box

Tags: forms, ms-access

I have created a form that searches through a table, following the instructions of John Big Booty, as can be seen here: https://access-programmers.co.uk/for...d.php?t=188663. The search form has a list box that has a query run whenever a text box is changed which allows me to search fields in one table but how do I adjust it to allow me to find related records stored in a second table. The database stores widow information and they are looked after by legatees.

The query has the following code in the criteria for each field you want to search Like "*" & [forms]![FRM_SearchMulti]![SrchText] & "*".

Each legatee is responsible for looking after multiple widows and any widow can be assigned to any legatee but any widow can only one legatee when she is assigned to one.

The search form is called FRM_SearchMulti and it searches through the widow table as I type. I want it so that you can type in a legatee and it will display the widows that have been assigned to that legatee typed in the search box. I seem to have hit a road block and everything I try doesn’t seem to work.

I have uploaded a version of the db with a lot of the information deleted, for privacy reasons, so if it is possible, could you describe to me how to do it and I will update the file with all the information in it please?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Have you looked at a UNION query? BTW, your link is not helpful.

Comment: https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=188663

This link works for me and I am not sure why the other link didn't work, I just copied it from the browser??

I am not very good at writing sql, what do I need to do with a union query?